# Using sort() vs. sorted() when sorting a slice of an array- why does sort() not work?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I have an input `array = [1,3,8,5,22,18,20,15,7,6,5]`

And I want to sort the numbers from 8 to 20 in the list inclusive of 8 and 20.

Why does the following not work:

```
array[2:7] = array[2:7].sort()     #TypeError: can only assign an iterable
```

while

```
array[2:7] = sorted(array[2:7])
```

works.

I understand conceptually that `sort()` sorts the input in-place, while `sorted()` creates a new list. But I couldn't get my head around how this is linked to the above.

Is it because `sort()` changes the indexing, and thus leading to the first instance not working? But this can't be, because the error is a TypeError where it must be an iterable?

Comment: It's because .sort returns None, sorted returns the new list.

Comment: Understood, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that `sorted` can be applied to any iterable, be it a list or an immutable tuple, a set or even a generator and will produce a list. On the other hand, `sort` is a method provided by some mutable and ordered containers, and will change *in place* its container.

What happens is that the slice returns a copy, that copy will be correctly sorted by the `sort` method, but the return value of the `sort` method is... `None`! So your code ends to:

```
array[2:7] = None
```

... and `None` is not an iterable...

Comment: @jonrsharpe My bad... I should have tested it. Unfortunately I cannot deleted this answer since it has been accepted so I have edited it... Thanks for the head up!

Answer (score 0):

`sort()` doesn't work because it doesn't return the array, it only changes the existing array.

This would work:

```
arr_slice = array[2:7]
arr_slice.sort() # Sorts arr_slice but returns None
array[2:7] = arr_slice
```